# Are there cross-border buses between Cyprus and North Cyprus?

Tags: buses, borders, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I'm curious whether there are any buses that cross the Cypriot-North Cypriot border. In particular (but not only) from Ercan airport

Comment: Why do you care? Do you need to get somewhere in particular?

Comment: I just want to know as much as possible in order plan to my trip. Haven't been able to find any info on this specific matter

Comment: Are you aware that as far as the ROC is concerned Ercan Airport is an illegal port of entry to Cyprus?

Comment: @PeterGreen Yes, but Cyprus cannot refuse entry to me as a Swedish (ie EU) citizen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.north-cyprus.travel/north-cyprus-transportation) it is possible to take a transfer from Larnaka airport in the South to Kyrenia in North Cyprus. Otherwise, I think (but can't prove it) that you will have to travel to Nicosia, cross the border and take the next bus.